# 'firebase_messaging/FirebaseMessagingPlugin.h' file not found

Tags: ios, swift, flutter

I'm trying to run my flutter app on ios, but u i get this error

> /ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:6:9:
>   'firebase_messaging/FirebaseMessagingPlugin.h' file not found

here is my podfile content

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def parse_KV_file(file, separator='=')
  file_abs_path = File.expand_path(file)
  if !File.exists? file_abs_path
    return [];
  end
  pods_ary = []
  skip_line_start_symbols = ["#", "/"]
  File.foreach(file_abs_path) { |line|
      next if skip_line_start_symbols.any? { |symbol| line =~ /^\s*#{symbol}/ }
      plugin = line.split(pattern=separator)
      if plugin.length == 2
        podname = plugin[0].strip()
        path = plugin[1].strip()
        podpath = File.expand_path("#{path}", file_abs_path)
        pods_ary.push({:name => podname, :path => podpath});
      else
        puts "Invalid plugin specification: #{line}"
      end
  }
  return pods_ary
end

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  # Prepare symlinks folder. We use symlinks to avoid having Podfile.lock
  # referring to absolute paths on developers' machines.
  system('rm -rf .symlinks')
  system('mkdir -p .symlinks/plugins')

  # Flutter Pods
  generated_xcode_build_settings = parse_KV_file('./Flutter/Generated.xcconfig')
  if generated_xcode_build_settings.empty?
    puts "Generated.xcconfig must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first."
  end
  generated_xcode_build_settings.map { |p|
    if p[:name] == 'FLUTTER_FRAMEWORK_DIR'
      symlink = File.join('.symlinks', 'flutter')
      File.symlink(File.dirname(p[:path]), symlink)
      pod 'Flutter', :path => File.join(symlink, File.basename(p[:path]))
    end
  }

  # Plugin Pods
  plugin_pods = parse_KV_file('../.flutter-plugins')
  plugin_pods.map { |p|
    symlink = File.join('.symlinks', 'plugins', p[:name])
    File.symlink(p[:path], symlink)
    pod p[:name], :path => File.join(symlink, 'ios')
  }
end

# Prevent Cocoapods from embedding a second Flutter framework and causing an error with the new Xcode build system.
install! 'cocoapods', :disable_input_output_paths => true

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
      config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '4.1'
    end
  end
end
```

and here is the result when I run `pod install`

> Analyzing dependencies Fetching podspec for `Flutter` from
>   `.symlinks/flutter/ios-release` Fetching podspec for
>   `firebase_messaging` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_messaging/ios`
>   Fetching podspec for `geolocator` from
>   `.symlinks/plugins/geolocator/ios` Fetching podspec for
>   `google_api_availability` from
>   `.symlinks/plugins/google_api_availability/ios` Fetching podspec for
>   `image_cropper` from `.symlinks/plugins/image_cropper/ios` Fetching
>   podspec for `image_picker` from `.symlinks/plugins/image_picker/ios`
>   Fetching podspec for `package_info` from
>   `.symlinks/plugins/package_info/ios` Fetching podspec for
>   `path_provider` from `.symlinks/plugins/path_provider/ios` Fetching
>   podspec for `permission_handler` from
>   `.symlinks/plugins/permission_handler/ios` Fetching podspec for
>   `shared_preferences` from `.symlinks/plugins/shared_preferences/ios`
>   Fetching podspec for `sqflite` from `.symlinks/plugins/sqflite/ios`
>   Fetching podspec for `webview_flutter` from
>   `.symlinks/plugins/webview_flutter/ios` Downloading dependencies Using
>   FMDB (2.7.5) Using Firebase (6.7.0) Using FirebaseAnalytics (6.1.1)
>   Using FirebaseAnalyticsInterop (1.4.0) Using FirebaseCore (6.2.1)
>   Using FirebaseCoreDiagnostics (1.0.1) Using
>   FirebaseCoreDiagnosticsInterop (1.0.0) Using FirebaseInstanceID
>   (4.2.3) Using FirebaseMessaging (4.1.3) Using Flutter (1.0.0) Using
>   GoogleAppMeasurement (6.1.1) Using GoogleDataTransport (1.1.3) Using
>   GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport (1.0.2) Using GoogleUtilities (6.2.5)
>   Using Protobuf (3.9.0) Using TOCropViewController (2.5.1) Using
>   firebase_messaging (0.0.1) Using geolocator (3.0.1) Using
>   google_api_availability (2.0.1) Using image_cropper (0.0.1) Using
>   image_picker (0.0.1) Using nanopb (0.3.901) Using package_info (0.0.1)
>   Using path_provider (0.0.1) Using permission_handler (3.2.2) Using
>   shared_preferences (0.0.1) Using sqflite (0.0.1) Using webview_flutter
>   (0.0.1) Generating Pods project Integrating client project Pod
>   installation complete! There are 12 dependencies from the Podfile and
>   28 total pods installed.

my Xcode version is 10.0

how can I fix it ? thanks in advance

Comment: I had this problem too. I solved updating everything, XCode, Flutter, Pod...

Comment: @Augusto i already try it, but still no help

Comment: Add `pod 'Firebase/Core'` at the top in your podfile and run `pod update`.

Comment: I think You should also add ```pod 'Firebase/Messaging'``` in your pod file.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When in doubt I just wipe and reinstall, rather than manually deal with cascading dependencies.

1) `rm` your `ios/Pods dir` and the Podfile.lock file (backing up of course)

2) `rm` your `~/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/`

3) `flutter clean`

4) `flutter packages get`

5) `pod repo update`

6) Either run your flutter executable as you normally would (which calls pod install), or manually run `pod install`.

Comment: Sorry for my lack of knowledge, but I don't know how to perform step no. 2. Could you explain it further to me? I can't find that folder

Comment: @JDE10 If you are using a Mac on Mac OS X, Navigate to Finder, Press Command + Shift + G and then paste the `~/.pub-cache/hosted/` and hit enter. There you will be able to find the `pub.dartlang.org` file. delete it manually.

Comment: Step 3 and Step 4 saved the day for me.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you opened the project by clicking the
**`your project name`.xcworkspace** file.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error additional times (as I remember).
Today I notice what exactly I've done to fix it:

```
cd ./ios
rm -R ../node_modules && ./Pods
yarn install
pod install
```

If you like, you better could clean your Project and close XCode - but for me the above steps are enough to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

try enabling bit code, because some frameworks work only when BITCODE is on.

config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'YES'