# Flutter release to ios 'firebase_messaging/FirebaseMessagingPlugin.h' file not found

Tags: firebase, flutter

Good day,

I've been struggling for a while to archive my app for release to Apple App Store.
However I keep getting the error: "'firebase_messaging/FirebaseMessagingPlugin.h' file not found" in XCode when archiving the project
[image: Error from XCode]
In this second screenshot, I have the Directorty showing the headers are present.
[image: directory in android studio]
I have also attempted the steps as in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58037230/3979046 but resulting in the same error.

Everything works when I run the project on an iphone in debug mode, this only occurs when trying to archive the project.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, i'm the one who have the same problem (from the link refrence). Have you try update your pod ?

Comment: Hi, I have tried to update the pod, but no luck